# How to do calculations based upon Django Model name instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two forms for two different category of accounts. I want to do some calculations based upon which category made the booking.

models.py

```
    class category1(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class category2(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class booking(models.Model):
        booked_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        amount = models.IntegerField()
        Total = models.IntegerField()

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.booked_by == category1:(NEED HELP OVER HERE, what query should I use)
                self.Total = self.amount * 2
            if self.booked_by == category2:(NEED HELP OVER HERE, what query should I use)
                self.Total = self.amount * 4
            super(booking,self).save()
```

forms.py

```
    class bookingform(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = booking
            exclude = ('booked_by','Total')
```

view.py

```
    class bookings_create(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
        login_url = 'Mel:user_login'
        form_class = bookingform
        template_name = 'Mel/bookings_form.html'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.booked_by = self.request.user
            return super(bookings_create, self).form_valid(form)
```

If the booking is made by category1 then do some calculations.
If booking is made by category2 do some calculations.

Comment: why you can't add field `type` to your model `category` and use `FK` in the field `booked_by`?

Comment: Is there any difference between `category1` and `category2` in terms of fields?

Comment: yes there are many differences between cat1 and cat2, The above fields are just an example for stackoverflow.

Comment: what are the differnce? what you write inside the `booked_by`?

Comment: Inside booked_by we get self.request.user. If the user belongs to cat1 we need to do a certain calculation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `User` is a standard django user model than this can be done like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if category1.objects.filter(user__username=self.booked_by).exists():
        self.Total = self.amount * 2
    if category2.objects.filter(user__username=self.booked_by).exists()
        self.Total = self.amount * 4
    super(booking,self).save()
```

It is better however to define `booked_by` as a foreign key to `User`. You will get database consistency in this case:

```
class booking(models.Model):
    booked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    Total = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if category1.objects.filter(user=self.booked_by).exists():
            self.Total = self.amount * 2
        if category2.objects.filter(user=self.booked_by).exists()
            self.Total = self.amount * 4
        super(booking,self).save()


class bookings_create(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = 'Mel:user_login'
    form_class = bookingform
    template_name = 'Mel/bookings_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.booked_by = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
        return super(bookings_create, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both categories have the same fields. There should be one `Category` model and use `Foreign Key` relationships.